# iOS Swift cannot set AWSSNSSubscribeInput.protocol parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using Swift for iOS app development in Xcode 6.1.1.

I am trying to programatically subscribe the app to a AWS SNS topic. As I know, you need to set:

```
let subscriptionRequest = AWSSNSSubscribeInput()
subscriptionRequest.protocol = "application"
subscriptionRequest.topicArn = kMyTopicArn
subscriptionRequest.endpoint = endPointARN
```

But the problem here is the IDE keeps telling me that

> subscriptionRequest.protocol = "application"

is not acceptable and it won't even build.
[image]

Really have no idea how to solve this. Could anyone help here? THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with the reserved words in Swift. To escape, just simple wrap the word in ``, e.g.

```
subscriptionRequest.`protocol` = "application"
```

See this for more: [Reserved Words In Swift and How to Escape Them](https://swiftcast.tv/articles/reserved-words-escaping)